# How to SelectListItem with Foreign Key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have 2 tables and I want to display them together using the Foreign Key. For Employees

| ID | FirstName | LastName | JobID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 1 |
| 2 | Mike | Sully | 1 |
| 3 | Ray | Man | 3 |

and Jobs

| JobID | JobTitle |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Animator |
| 2 | 3D Artist |
| 3 | Illustrator |

How can I make it show up in a dropdownlist as

|  |
| --- |
| John Doe (Animator) |
| Mike Sully (Animator) |
| Ray Man (3D Artist) |

My Model

```
        public string Employee { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeList { get; set; }
```

My Code

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEmployee()
        {
            var employee = db.Employees.Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.EmployeeID.ToString(),
                Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName 
            }).ToList();
            var placeholder = new SelectListItem() { Value = null, Text = "Select Employee..." };

            //employee.Insert(0, placeholder);
            return new SelectList(employee, "Value", "Text");

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may fetch the job title by job ID, like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> titles = db.Employees.Select(
  e => string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})",
    e.FirstName,
    e.LastName,
    db.Jobs.Single(j => j.JobID == e.JobID)
      .JobTitle)
);
```

`titles` contains the items for your drop-down list.